# Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python programming and trying to solve an Spoj challenge
was trying to code Palindrome numbers. My code :

```
num = int(input("Enter a number"))

def test_num(number):
    num_list = list(str(number))
    elements = []
    for j in range(len(num_list)):
        elements.insert(0, num_list[j])
        result = ''.join(str(e) for e in elements)
     if result == number:
        print(num)
    else:
        print("Unmatched", number, result)
        test_num((number + 1))


test_num(num)
```

if I input, num = 9
my output turns into an infinite loop. Apparently the if statement is not coming True.

```
Enter a number9
Unmatched 9 9
Unmatched 10 01
Unmatched 11 11    # This is where it is supposed to break 
Unmatched 12 21
Unmatched 13 31
Unmatched 14 41
Unmatched 15 51
Unmatched 16 61
Unmatched 17 71
```

Series is supposeds to break when result == num (or in this case 11 )
yet it continues on and on to infinite loop.
You can also give some suggestions to the code if you like

Comment: `range(len(num_list))` will keep growing as you insert elements into `num_list`.  So your `for` loop will never exit.

Comment: It looks like you're comparing an integer with a string (if result==number).  You either need to keep number as a string, or convert result to an integer before you compare them.

Comment: Hint: If you used `print("Unmatched", repr(number), repr(result))` then it would be a lot easier to see what happened.

Comment: Also - why are you trying to use recursion here? Also - what criteria is your function supposed to break on? You say when number is 11, but your input num is 9 - so not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @JonClements The challenge is that if I input a number, it is supposed to print the the smallest number possible (which is greater than out input number) such that its a Palindrome  number i;e a number when when read from left to right or right to left gives us the same value. Eg: 11, or 121, or 12321 etc.

Comment: @Bing in your example `input: 9` why does it not break on `9 9`, but instead it breaks on `11 11`? Isn't `99` smaller than `1111`? I mean shouldn't it break on the first palindrome larger than the input number? Can you provide the link to the SPOJ problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @downshift http://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/

Comment: @Bing I don't know how to change your code, but the same question is at: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/81962/finding-the-next-palindrome-code. maybe it can help you (or here is another more complex solution https://cshaven.wordpress.com/2013/10/31/5-the-next-palindrome/) there are many solutions

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for recursion. This can be solved by a simple `while` Loop. Following code works

```
num = int(input("Enter a number "))

def next_palindrome(number):
    new_number = number+1
    while True:
        string = str(new_number)
        if string == ''.join(string[::-1]):
            return new_number
        else:
            print('{} not a palindrome'.format(new_number))
            new_number += 1

print('{} is a palindrome'.format(next_palindrome(num)))
```

For example input = 15, you will get the following output

```
Enter a number 15    
16 is not a palindrome
17 is not a palindrome
18 is not a palindrome
19 is not a palindrome
20 is not a palindrome
21 is not a palindrome
22 is a palindrome
```